# Google chrome shows npapi pugins installed on firefox

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

When I type `chrome://plugins/` in chrome, it shows `npapi` plugins installed on Firefox.  Do Chrome and Firefox share `npapi` plugins register at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins` path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is chrome and Firefox shares npapi plugins register at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins` path?

Yes. All browsers that support NPAPI plugins support that registration mechanism.

Comment: Georg Fritzsche thanks for answer i have one more question there are some NPAPI plugins which are not available on paths i.e on 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins' or 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions' are also shown by google chrome. is there any other mechanism used search NPAPI plugin by google chrome?

Comment: Yes, different browsers support other different mechanims as well - e.g. [this one](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi) for Chrome. I'm not sure about all the paths that Chrome supports, are you trying to solve a specific problem?

Comment: thanks for reply. my problem is I am installing npapi plugin in Firefox by adding path of my plugin to registry i.e at 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins' location. just i want to know why my chrome browser also showing the same npapi plugin as i haven't installed on chrome ? do have any link to document so that will clear my confusion about NPAPI plugin mechanism. that will very helpful for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: The common documentation that Google also points to is [the plugin docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins), specifically [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Registering_Plug-ins). This doesn't have an official standard, just "what works across browsers". Don't forget that you should be investigating alternatives to NPAPI if possible as NPAPI is getting less and less support.